# Find value that is missing from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables I am using to compare data and find where a record may be missing from one of the tables.  The tables are A_Client, A_USER_Defined and A_Group_Member.

A_CLIENT contains: ClientName, ClientUID

A_USER_Defined contains: ClientUID, LOB

A_GROUP_MEMBER contains: ID, ClientUID

So the common column in each is ClientUID.

I am trying to find the Device(s) where defined.lob = 'value1' and does not exist in the member table where member.id = 'value2'

So far my searches comes up empty and am guessing it's something to do with the different joins? Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT A_CLIENT.ClientName
     , A_CLIENT.ClientUID
     , A_USER_DEFINED.LOB
  FROM A_CLIENT
       INNER JOIN 
       A_USER_DEFINED ON A_CLIENT.ClientUID = A_USER_DEFINED.ClientUID
 WHERE A_USER_DEFINED.LOB = 'value1' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT ClientUID
                     FROM A_GROUP_MEMBER
                    WHERE GroupID = 'value2'
                  )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a query which you think might be close to working?

Comment: Also, which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
select cli.ClientName, cli.ClientUID, def.LOB
   from A_CLIENT cli
      inner join A_USER_DEFINED def on def.ClientGUID = cli.ClientGUID and def.LOB = 'value1'
      left join A_GROUP_MEMBER grp on grp.ClientUID = cli.ClientUID and mbr.ID = 'value2'
   where mbr.UID is null

select cli.ClientName, cli.ClientUID, def.LOB
   from A_CLIENT cli, A_USER_DEFINED def
   where def.ClientGUID = cli.ClientGUID and def.LOB = 'value1'
      and cli.ClientUID not in (select ClientUID from A_GROUP_MEMBER where GroupID = 'value2')
```

and various other possibilities, depending on what type of join or predicate your engine is more comfortable with

Edit: the question and the table/field names changed considerably since I posted my answer. They seem to have settled down now and so I changed my code to suit.

Note: the EXISTS predicate in your query only checks whether are any records at all with ID = 'value2'; it should quite probably check only for records that also have a matching UID.

Also, there seems to be some confusion potential between ClientUID and Client**G**UID. Is that a typo or does your DB actually have both names in it? If it is the latter then someone is in dire need of being educated with a blunt instrument.

Answer (score 0):

```
select devices.* 
  from devices
  left join member 
    on devices.ClientUID = member.ClientUID
   and devices.lob = 'value1'   
   and member.id = 'value2' 
 where member.ClientUID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually quite close and just need to correlate the not the exists subquery. Without sample data I haven't tested, but I think that minimal correction will fix your query.

```
SELECT A_CLIENT.ClientName
     , A_CLIENT.ClientUID
     , A_USER_DEFINED.LOB
  FROM A_CLIENT 
       INNER JOIN 
       A_USER_DEFINED ON A_CLIENT.ClientUID = A_USER_DEFINED.ClientUID
 WHERE A_USER_DEFINED.LOB = 'value1' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT ClientUID 
                     FROM A_GROUP_MEMBER 
                    WHERE A_GROUP_MEMBER.ClientUID = A_CLIENT.ClientUID
                      AND GroupID = 'value2'
                  )
```

I'd probably use some table alias ti make that easier to read but ymmv:

```
SELECT c.ClientName
     , c.ClientUID
     , u.LOB
  FROM A_CLIENT c
       INNER JOIN 
       A_USER_DEFINED u ON c.ClientUID = u.ClientUID
 WHERE A_USER_DEFINED.LOB = 'value1' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT 1
                     FROM A_GROUP_MEMBER g
                    WHERE g.ClientUID = c.ClientUID
                      AND GroupID = 'value2'
                  )
```